# Can Hive be installed on Hadoop 2.2?

Tags: hadoop, hive

The 'Getting Started' page on Hive's website shows that it requires Hadoop 0.20.x.

Has anyone successfully installed it on recent versions? Specifically 2.2.0?

Comment: I have it running on 2.0.5-alpha.  I'd be surprised if it didn't run on 2.2.0

Comment: Thanks, I wanted some semblance of knowing it'll work before heading in that direction. I'll report back after my attempt.

Answer (score 1):

We have Hive (v 0.12.0) running on Hadoop 2.2.0 (2-node cluster) for the last 2 weeks. The performance improvements alone are  worth it but still seeing some Hadoop/Yarn related warnings that need to be resolved but aren't causing any problems.

Answer (score 0):

I think the trunk code should work, while for 0.12 branch, doesn't it need to hack protobuf version to work with hadoop 2.2?

Comment: Didn't have to do anything special for hive, outside of setting up the derby server for multiple users to work together. Setting up the hadoop 2.2.0 cluster did take some trial and error but don't recall having to hack protobuf.